# communication between processes with semaphores FULL,EMPTY,MUTEX?

Tags: c, process, ipc, semaphore

I trying to study the inter process comunication. I trying to write a program that send a message between father and child. First the father read a input file and send the rows to child, the child re-send the rows to the father. The processs communicate with the semaphores (FULL,EMPTY,MUTEX) using WAIT and SIGNAL functions. I use 6 semaphores. Why the last father_final doesn't receive nothing ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

#define DIM 1024

#define MUTEX 0 // sem mutex
#define FULL 1  // sem full
#define EMPTY 2 // sem empty

#define MUTEX2 3 // sem mutex
#define FULL2 4  // sem full
#define EMPTY2 5 // sem empty

#define TYPE_P 2
#define TYPE_F 3
#define TYPE_FN 4

typedef struct
{
  char text[DIM];
  int eof;
  long type;
  int nChild;
} msg;

int WAIT(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
  struct sembuf ops[1] = {{sem_num, -1, 0}};
  return semop(sem_id, ops, 1);
}

int SIGNAL(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
  struct sembuf ops[1] = {{sem_num, +1, 0}};
  return semop(sem_id, ops, 1);
}

void father(int shm_id, int sem_id, char *filename, msg *p)
{
  FILE *r_stream;
  char tmp[DIM];

  if ((r_stream = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
  {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (fgets(tmp, DIM, r_stream) != NULL)
  {
    printf("Father -> %s", tmp);
    WAIT(sem_id, EMPTY);
    WAIT(sem_id, MUTEX);
    strcpy(p->text, tmp);
    p->eof = 0;
    p->type = TYPE_F;
    p->nChild = 1;
    SIGNAL(sem_id, MUTEX);
    SIGNAL(sem_id, FULL);
  }

  WAIT(sem_id, EMPTY);
  WAIT(sem_id, MUTEX);
  strcpy(p->text, "-1\n");
  p->eof = 1;
  p->type = TYPE_F;
  p->nChild = 1;
  SIGNAL(sem_id, MUTEX);
  SIGNAL(sem_id, FULL);

  fclose(r_stream);

  shmdt(p);

  exit(0);

}

void filter(int shm_id, int sem_id, int child, msg *p)
{

  char text[DIM];
  int eof;
  long type;
  int nChild;

  while (1)
  {

    WAIT(sem_id, FULL);
    WAIT(sem_id, MUTEX);

    WAIT(sem_id, EMPTY2);
    WAIT(sem_id, MUTEX2);

    strcpy(text, p->text);
    eof = p->eof;
    type = p->type;
    nChild = p->nChild;
    printf("Filter-> %s", text);

    printf("Send to father: %s", text);
    SIGNAL(sem_id, MUTEX2);
    SIGNAL(sem_id, FULL2);

    SIGNAL(sem_id, MUTEX);
    SIGNAL(sem_id, EMPTY);
  }

  exit(0);
}

void father_final(int shm_id2, int sem_id, msg *p2)
{

  while (1)
  {
    WAIT(sem_id, FULL2);
    WAIT(sem_id, MUTEX2);

    if(strcmp(p2->text,"-1\n")==0)break;

    printf("Messaggio ricevuto: %s\n", p2->text);

    SIGNAL(sem_id, MUTEX2);
    SIGNAL(sem_id, EMPTY2);
  }

  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /* code */
  int shm_id, sem_id, shm_id2;
  msg *p, *p2;

  if (argc == 1 || argc == 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "uso: %s file.txt filter-1...filte-n \n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  // creo area di memoria condivisa
  if ((shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(msg), IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
  {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
  }

  // attacco area di memoria
  if ((p = (msg *)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (msg *)-1)
  {
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1);
  }

  // creo i semafori
  if ((sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 3, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
  {
    perror("semget");
    exit(1);
  }

  // inizializzo semafori
  semctl(sem_id, MUTEX, SETVAL, 1);
  semctl(sem_id, EMPTY, SETVAL, 1);
  semctl(sem_id, FULL, SETVAL, 0);
  semctl(sem_id, MUTEX2, SETVAL, 1);
  semctl(sem_id, EMPTY2, SETVAL, 1);
  semctl(sem_id, FULL2, SETVAL, 0);

  int child = argc - 2;
  char *filename = argv[1];

  if (fork() == 0)
  {

    filter(shm_id, sem_id, child, p);
  }
  else
  {
    father(shm_id, sem_id, filename, p);
  }
  
  father_final(shm_id,sem_id,p);

  // distruggo area di memoria condivisa
  shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
  // rimuovo i semafoti
  semctl(sem_id, FULL, IPC_RMID, 0);
  semctl(sem_id, EMPTY, IPC_RMID, 0);
  semctl(sem_id, MUTEX, IPC_RMID, 0);
  semctl(sem_id, FULL2, IPC_RMID, 0);
  semctl(sem_id, EMPTY2, IPC_RMID, 0);
  semctl(sem_id, MUTEX2, IPC_RMID, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
Father -> Fratelli d'Italia,
Father -> l'Italia s'è desta,
Filter-> Fratelli d'Italia,
Send to father: Fratelli d'Italia,
Father -> dell'elmo di Scipio
Filter-> l'Italia s'è desta,
Send to father: l'Italia s'è desta,
Father -> s'è cinta la testa.
Filter-> dell'elmo di Scipio
Send to father: dell'elmo di Scipio
Father -> Dov'è la vittoria?
Filter-> s'è cinta la testa.
Send to father: s'è cinta la testa.
Father -> Le porga la chioma,
Filter-> Dov'è la vittoria?
Send to father: Dov'è la vittoria?
Father -> ché schiava di RomaIddio la creò.
Filter-> Le porga la chioma,
Send to father: Le porga la chioma,
Filter-> ché schiava di RomaIddio la creò.
Send to father: ché schiava di RomaIddio la creò.
Filter-> -1
Send to father: -1
```

I don't receive messages like "Msg received -> ......"

Comment: Re "*I should get the latest messages like "Msg received -> ......"*", Your program never prints `Msg received -> ` anywhere.

Comment: Also, the call to `father_final` is never reached by either process, as they call `exit(0);` before reaching that point.

Comment: The program prints father.
Only thing that doesn't print is Msg received -> ......

Comment: I would like to understand where I go wrong with the process communication

Comment: Start by fixing the question.

Comment: If I remove exit(0) I get segmentation fault

Comment: I do not know what kind of title of my request

Comment: I mean fix the very last line of your question. There's no `Msg recevied ->` anywhere in your program

Comment: It must be so. The child process calls the parent again

Comment: And maybe explain when you want `father_final` to be called, by which process and when.

Comment: Actually the child should make changes to the received line and then send it back to the parent. In the code I don't do it for simplicity, I would like to make them communicate first.

Comment: oops, nevermind. I'm wrong. Deleted the incorrect comments.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand correctly.
1 - The father reads the lines and sends to the son.
2- The child receives the rows ( modifies them) and sends them back to the parent.
3 - The parent prints the modified lines.
For simplicity I'm not editing the lines, do you understand?

Comment: I asked for help for this, but you're not giving me much help

Comment: I still do not understand